# linq to sql duplicates in query eith join

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a linq to sql query that produces duplicates. i can seem to figure out how to eliminate these duplicate records. Maybe someone on here can help. The idea is to retrieve the sum of the "total" from table2 that occurs for dates in table 1 that are greater than dates of table2 and also have dates in table2 that are greater than 2011-01-01. What i have achieves this but because of **duplicates i get exactly double the sum**. Your help is much appreciated

Table structure:

```
table1:  id, date
table2: id, date, total
```

The query

```
from t1 in table1
                    join t2 in table2 on t1.id equals t2.id into x
                    from y in x
                    where t1.id == "123" && t1.date > y.date && y.date > DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01") 
                    group t1 by new { y.total} into g

                    select g.Sum(t1 => t1.total);
```

Comment: You probably have two rows in t2 matching one row in t1. Join produces two rows, sum sums both rows now with duplicate values in t1 fields. You should replace join with where.

Comment: I am trying this but cant seem to figure out how to write this out correctly this is what i have so far var query = from t1 in table
            where (from t2 in t2 
                   where t1.id == "123" && t1.id == t2.id && t1.date > t2.date 
                   && t2.date > DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01")
                   select t2.total)
            group t1 by t1.id into g
            select g.Sum(t2 => t2.total);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the query in multiple steps:

Select the data you want:

```
var data = 
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
where t1.Id == "123" && t1.Date > t2.Date && t2.Date > DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01")
select new {t1.Id, t2.Date, t2.Total};
```

Call distinct to avoid repeating items:

```
var distinct = data.Distinct();
```

Get the sum:

```
return distinct.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                .Select(g => g.Sum(item => item.Total));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be grouping it by an Id / Key and summing it by the total?

as in

```
  group t1 by new { y.Id} into g
```

Comment: Another thing you could try is looking at the SQL this produces, copy and paste it into your SQL Server Management studio and run it in section to see where things are doubling up.
context.Log = new DebuggerWriter();